# How show the map $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$, defined as $f(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, continuity

**Question:** I want to show the map $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$, defined as $f(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$.

**Issue:** I know how to prove this via the epsilon-delta way. I want to prove this using the projection functions $p_1,p_2: \mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ where $p_1$ maps $(x,y)\rightarrow x$, similarly for $p_2$. Now my books says via a result based on continuous functions from $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ that the sum of $p_1+p_2$ is continuous but I don't see how that would be possible as the domain of the functions are $\mathbb R$ and not $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: It is a polynomial function: how continuous do you want it to be? It is also the sum of two projections, which are continuous *in each variable* (and here you can widen the argument from $\;\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc I never questioned whether it was continuous. My book is showing me an alternative way which I don't logically agree with. I accept the projection functions are continuous $\forall(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ but I don't see how you can say the sum of the two projections is continuous based on results from real to real functions (i.e. if $f,g$ are continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ then so is $f+g$, I don't understand how they have applied this...)

Comment: @MPW Is there a way to prove the question using the projection functions, but only using results based on continuous real-valued functions from the reals.

Comment: If you concede that addition $s:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\rightarrow R$ (with $s(x+y)=x+y$) is continuous, then $f=s\circ (p_1\times p_2)$ is continuous.

Comment: @MPW so there isn't really a clear cut way then....you have gone from the results I want to show and forcefully got $p_1,p_2$ involved it seems.

Comment: This bloody site (or my browser) won't let me edit my comment, so I'll start another. You need to show that the Cartesian product of continuous functions (namely, projections) is continuous. That will give you the map between the proper spaces.